# Perl Format the Output in nice way

Tags: perl, formatting

I have written a perl code for processing file 'Output.txt' which has below Content.

```
  new.example.com 28
  new.example.com 28
  example.com 28
  example.com 29
  example.com 29
  example.com 29
  example.com 29
  orginal.com 28
  orginal.com 29
  orginal.com 30
  orginal.com 31
  expand.com  31
```

And file 'domain.txt' has list of domain Names  which i need to match against File 'Output.txt'

```
new.example.com
example.com
orginal.com
test.com
new.com
```

I could manage to write PERL code like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
open(LOGFILE,"Output.txt") or die("Could not open log file.");
my $domain_name = 'domain.txt' ;
open(DOM, $domain_name);
my @r_contents = <LOGFILE>;
close(LOGFILE);    
while(<DOM>) {
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;
    my @lowercase = map { lc } @r_contents;
    my @grepNames = grep  /^$line/, @lowercase;
    foreach (@grepNames) {
        if ( grep  /^$line/, @lowercase ) {
            $domains{lc($_)}++ ;            }
    }
}

close(DOM) ;    
foreach my $domain (sort keys %domains) {
    my %seen ;
    ($Dname, $WeekNum) = split(/\s+/, $domain);
    my @array1 = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } $WeekNum;
    push @array2, @array1;
    my @array4 = "$domains{$domain} $domain" ;
    push @matrix,@array4 ;
}
   printf "%-10s %-25s %-25s\n", 'DoaminName', "Week $array2[0]" ,"Week $array2[1]","Week $array2[2]";
   print " @matrix \n";
```

current Output looks like this.

```
 DoaminName         Week 28        week29   week30  week 31
 2 new.example.com 35
 1 example.com 28
 4 example.com 29
 1 orginal.com 28
 1 orginal.com 29
 1 orginal.com 30
 1 orginal.com 31
```

But i trying  re-write the perl code to print the output like this .Please help me to correct the code.

```
Domain/WeekNumber   Week28       Week29        Week30        Week31
new.example.com     2            No            No            No
example.com         1            4             NO            NO
orginal.com         1            1              1             1
```

Comment: Use http://p3rl.org/Text::Table to format the output to a table.

Comment: can somebody help me on this...?thanks in advance

Comment: Once you get your data organized by domain name and week you can just use a padded printf like you have for your column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the desired output, only I also sorted the output.

If you have long website names, add tabs in the code as necessary.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
open my $fh, "<", "Output.txt" or die "could not open Output.txt\n";

my %data;
my %weeks;
while(<$fh>){
    chomp;
    $_=~ m/(.*?)\s++(\d++)/;
    my $site=$1;
    my $week=$2;
    $weeks{$week}++;
    $data{$site}{$week}++;
}

print "Domain/WeekNumber";

for my $week (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %weeks){
    print"\tWeek$week";
}
print"\n";

for my $site(sort keys %data){
    print"$site\t\t";
    for my $week (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %weeks){
            unless(defined $data{$site}{$week} ){
                    print"NO\t";
            }else{
                    print $data{$site}{$week} ."\t";
            }
    }
    print"\n";
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

But 'Output.txt'have got dynamic data.The week Number Will keep on change when ever i pull data from Mail log for current month.

print "Domain/WeekNumber\tWeek28\tWeek29\tWeek30\tWeek31\n"; and  for my $week (qw(28 29 30 31)) will not work for me since the week number chnages every month.

Comment: This change should be trivial.  I basically wrote the program for you.  You should read a book.  Your code seems to indicate that your problem may be compounded by a lack of familiarity with Perl.

Comment: And also 'Output.txt' have thousands of entries i need only 'domain.txt' to matched from that list...That is were i stuck..

Comment: ,Yes am a newbie in Perl.But i could mange to write till that .I tried my level best to sort it out.but no luck.Thanks for you help.It will be great if you could help me further...

Comment: Edited to handle whatever weeks it finds.

Comment: ,Realy gr8..Thank you very much .Its working for me ..Thank you once again.Last one week i was playing with this.But you solved it one minute.

Comment: Haha.  Your are welcome.  Remember to upvote/choose my answer ;)

Comment: Am getting below error when i run the above  code while parse large file" Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(.*?)\s++ <-- HERE (\d++)/ at ./test.pl line 14." " and line 14 is from the script is " $_=~ m/(.*?)\s++(\d++)/;" ...Could you please hlep me ?

Comment: ppnair: You are likely on an old version of Perl.  Try changing the ++ to + (your version does not seem to understand what the possessive quantifier ++ is).

Comment: The reason I wrote the ++ like I did is a slight possible gain in efficiency, but it will run the same as + in this case.

Comment: ,Is there any way to restrict printing only 4 weeks?currently it will print all the weeks which present in the file.When i take one month loge file,unfortunately it is having 5 weeks logs.i need only 4 weeks.

Comment: You may find the following link useful.  This link contains a list of Perl books freely available online.  http://www.perl.org/books/library.html